# Uniquely identifying a UTXO

Tags: transactions, hash, script, utxo

I see two ways:

> Txid + index
>
> Txid + script hash

Pros of the **txid + index**:

- Simple and short

Cons of **txid + index**:

- It relies on array iteration being deterministic and all third party services using the same iteration method.

**Txid + script hash** does not rely on iteration order and since script hashes are stored on the blockchain they are not malleable after 6 confirmations.

Which would be the preferred way to go?

Comment: What if there are two outputs of the same transaction with the same scriptPubKey, but different amount? Also why would index not be deterministic? Transactions have a well defined order of their outputs. It's also not a question, as the Bitcoin protocol requires referring to the output being spent using txid+index.

Comment: @PieterWuille Great points, didn't consider multiple identical scripts having different amounts. That completely excludes that option. I will rely on txid+index like bitcoin then. Thanks a lot!